# set random forest to classification

Tags: r, random-forest

I am attempting a random forest on some data where the class variables is binary (either 1 or 0).  Here is the code I'm running:

```
forest.model <- randomForest(x = ticdata2000[,1:85], y = ticdata2000[,86], 
                       ntree=500,
                       mtry=9,
                       importance=TRUE,
                       norm.votes=TRUE,
                       na.action=na.roughfix,
                       replace=FALSE,
                             )
```

But when the forest gets to the end, I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In randomForest.default(x = ticdata2000[, 1:85], y = ticdata2000[,  :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

The answer, of course, is no.  I don't want to do regression.  I have a single, discrete variable that only takes on 2 classes.  Of course, when I run predictions with this model, I get continuous numbers, when I want a list of zeroes and ones.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to get this to use regression and not classification?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your response column to a factor using `as.factor` (or just `factor`). Since you've stored that variable as *numeric* 0's and 1's, R rightly interprets it as a numeric variable. If you want R to treat it differently, you have to tell it so.

This is mentioned in the documentation under the `y` argument:

> A response vector. If a factor, classification is assumed, otherwise
>   regression is assumed. If omitted, randomForest will run in
>   unsupervised mode.

Comment: Please be explicit. The current randomForest pdf does not contain information directly on the `Y` argument.

Comment: @oaxacamatt I'm not sure I follow your comment; is it directed at my answer? As far as I can tell, my block quote is still a direct quote of the documentation of the current version on CRAN. Am I misunderstanding you?